# Custom 'rendering' of Display Value completing a Survey in SurveyJS

Tags: surveyjs

I can't find anything in the documentation of SurveyJS. If there is something I missed, a link would be great!

We have implemented a Custom Widget as described [here](https://surveyjs.io/Documentation/Survey-Creator/?id=Create-Custom-Widget) and it works well. What we want to do next is to change the Display Value on the 'Survey Results' section when testing the survey from the creator. In other words, a 'Signature' question's result is displayed as `data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAASwAAADICAYAAABS39xVAAAUGklEQVR4nO3dz28j53kH8PwZFYM6btOGAnIwWpRCe2iLAFSK2IgLUD20PTRa9GL4IiUHF2hBnZxDUuoSyT8623rLxAmpbFdCxaVn15n1luQOC3K7IW1yzRKt6HpEgQfyMOSBGPDy9CC9s8MhJc4MZzjvkN8PwIN3sdrZxerr933meZ/3KwQAEBBf8fsBAACsQmABQGAgsAAgMBBYABAYCCwACAwEFgAEBgILAAIDgQUAgYHAAoDAQGABQGAgsABM1JFGtX6Xav0upZUGHZ1ffm63qhOfYu+Cir0LqvW7fj/2SkBgwcpSRxqJnTPab5bp1tMsbebSFMocUihzSGFRoIiUpJh8rH+2y9mx/47mUhSRkhQWBf3XrYsCbRVPaLci0e1WlWr9LinDgd9...`

but we don't want to do this, we want to render the result... but not for the signature but for our custom widget.

Also, is there a function to review your answers before submitting? If there is, we'll most probably also need to display a rendered answer of our custom widget here.

Answer (score 2):

**Showing a preview of answers before submitting**

There is a SurveyJS feature, which does that. To enable it you need to add a survey-level parameter called `showPreviewBeforeComplete`. You can choose from the following values:

- showAllQuestions
- showAnsweredQuestions

This feature will automatically render all images or signatures on the preview page.

The feature is also available through the Survey Creator's UI under the "Navigation" section of the survey settings panel.

Here's an example:

```
{
 "pages": [
  {
   "name": "page1",
   "elements": [
    {
     "type": "signaturepad",
     "name": "question1"
    }
   ]
  }
 ],
 "showPreviewBeforeComplete": "showAnsweredQuestions"
}
```

**Rendering uploaded images**

If you would like to create your own widget, which renders uploaded images or signatures, you can base it on the HTML widget. It should contain an `<img src='{question1}' />` tag, where the value of the src parameter should be the base64 data string, which you retrieved from the signature pad widget.

Here's an example:

```
{
 "pages": [
  {
   "name": "page1",
   "elements": [
    {
     "type": "signaturepad",
     "name": "question1"
    }
   ]
  },
  {
   "name": "page2",
   "elements": [
    {
     "type": "html",
     "name": "question2",
     "html": "<img src='{question1}' />"
    }
   ]
  }
 ]
}
```

Comment: Thanks! We'll give the 'showPreviewBeforeComplete' option a go.

As for the other thing, what needs to be rendered would not necessarily be an image. There is some logic that needs to run over the answer to process it to display it in a more 'human readable' way. So we're really hoping there is some way to manually change the contents of the 'td' for the Display Value.